# JS: асинхронная работа setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Есть простой код:

```js
console.log(1); 
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(2); 
},0);
console.log(3);
```

он выведет следующее:

```
1
3
2
```

То есть, сначала срабатывают обычные console.log и только после этого console.log, обернутый в setTimeOut. С чем это связано? Асинхронность setTimeOut? Особенности работы таймеров в JS?

Comment: блин, тут целую статью нужно написать:D

Comment: Может есть ссылка уже на готовую? :) Честно говоря, сам не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В самом простом случае правило такое: все что находится в `setTimeout` не **ВЫПОЛНИТСЯ** через `N` миллисекунд, а **ДОБАВИТСЯ В СТЕК** вызовов. Но перед фактическим вызовом, если в стеке еще есть что-то, оно выполнится первым.

Поэтому у вас таймаут с 0мс добавляет `console.log` в конец стека. А перед ним уже есть еще два вызова. Это очень грубое объяснение.

Вот статья, которая описывает более полно что там происходит вообще: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/340508/

Comment: Да, в статье это описано очень подробно. Спасибо.

Comment: По итогу, данное поведение кода все же объясняется наличием таймера. setTimeout вызывается (добавляется в стек вызовов) после первого console.log, но в свою очередь, даже, если время выполнения 0 мс, он создает таймер, далее следует добавление console.log(3) в стек вызовов и только после этого сработает таймер, который вызовет callback, который в свою очередь добавит наш console.log(2) в стек вызовов и выведет 2.

Коротко говоря, вызов setTimeout со вторым аргументом, равным 0, откладывает вызов коллбэка до момента очищения стека вызовов.